# Creating a loop of many lists

Tags: python

I have a list of data:

```
data_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], ...]
```

I am trying to assign each element to a separate list so that:

```
Bin1 = [1,2,3]
Bin2 = [4,5,6]
....
Bin100 = [..,..,..]
```

I'm not sure how to do this without doing the manual way of initializing lists 1 by 1. Tried searching for a function how to go about it but have not found anything.

Once I have the lists initialized, I'd need to append the data from data_list:

```
for i in range(0, len(data_list)):
     bin1.append(data_list[i][1])
     bin2.append(data_list[i][2])
     .......
```

Again, a shortcut way of doing this would be so useful!

Comment: You already have the lists in... a list! There's no need to do this at all. `data_list[0]` is essentially `Bin1` (different values in the square brackets will give you different bins)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary if you wanted to access the lists with a key like `"Bin1"`:

```
data_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(data_list, 1):
    d['Bin{}'.format(i)] = v

print(d) # >>> {'Bin1': [1, 2, 3], 'Bin3': [7, 8, 9], 'Bin2': [4, 5, 6]}

print(d['Bin1'])  # >>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Or using a dict comprehension:

```
d = {'Bin{}'.format(i): v for i,v in enumerate(data_list, 1)}
```

Comment: `enumerate(data_list, 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write below code

```
l = [ [i,i+1,i+2] for i in range(1,YOUR_MAX_LENGTH,3) ]
```

hope this helps

Comment: Be careful with 1-letter variable names. `l` looks suspiciously like `I` and `1` and `|`. How about `my_list` or something (since we don't really know what it represents)?

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension to make a dictionary of lists, note this makes copies:

```
data_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

# To make copies
separate_lists = {'bin'+str(i): sublist
                  for i,sublist in enumerate(data_list,1)}

print (separate_lists)
```

To make a dictionary without making copies, this should work:

```
# To remove sublists from data_list and put them in the dictionary
separate_lists_not_copied = {}
for i in range(1,len(data_list)+1):
    separate_lists_not_copied['bin'+str(i)] = data_list.pop(0)

print (separate_lists_not_copied)
```

Both print:

```
{'bin3': [7, 8, 9], 'bin1': [1, 2, 3], 'bin2': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: Minor - you can have `enumerate()` start at `1` to avoid the `+1` in `str(i+1)`, e.g. `enumerate(data_list, 1)`, then just `str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#locals) to create variable name on-the-fly and iterate over all your sublists.

For those who are not aware of this function:

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table.
>
> Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function
>   blocks, but not in class blocks.

```
data_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

for i, sublist in enumerate(data_list, 1):
  locals()['bin_{}'.format(i)] = sublist

print bin_1 # [1, 2, 3]
print bin_3 # [7,8,9]
```

**NOTE**: Don't use uppercase on variable name since it is use by convention on for python classes. so `bin_1` is a better name than `Bin1`